# Weird UITableViewCell animation when changing the UITableView frame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a iPhone app that I'm working on and it works alot like the sms.app. Basically, when you click the keyboard, the tableView shrinks to fit when they keyboard is shown. And when you click out of it, it hides and the TableView goes back to it's original height.

My problem is, when changing my UITableView frame back to the original size, cells that weren't shown and now were have a weird animation before it shows up. I can mainly tell because of the images. They start out big towards the center then resize to where they should be. Is this a setting in the UITableView? Or is is just my code?

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// InitWithStyle
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// Add subviews here! EX:
// [[cell contenView] addSubview:theObject];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the UITableView style twice to two different styles,

default:

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

and Subtitle:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`
```

set it here to whichever style you want and delete the other.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

So whats happening is you create a new cell when needed then create another cell of a different style.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. But now my whole table view is messed up. I did as you said and did `if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`, added my subviews, then closed it `}`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle? I think thats what you had because it was being created second